# Correct User/Roles Entity relations

Tags: php, frameworks, symfony5

My question is more abstract than specified.

We have two tables "Users" and "Roles" and one which is a relation between the previous two. My question is, what should be the correct relationship between the two tables in order to be able to use the Login and Registration from Symfony documentation. I think I'm missing something in the whole concept.
Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I've create tables and relations via doctrine terminal

User entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="There is already an account with this email")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->date_created = new \DateTime();
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150, nullable=true)
     */
    private $first_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150, nullable=true)
     */
    private $last_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $active = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $date_created;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isVerified = false;

    /**
     * @var Collection|Roles[]
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Roles")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *      name="user_roles",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $roles;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->first_name;
    }

    public function setFirstName(?string $first_name): self
    {
        $this->first_name = $first_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->last_name;
    }

    public function setLastName(?string $last_name): self
    {
        $this->last_name = $last_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getActive(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->active;
    }

    public function setActive(bool $active): self
    {
        $this->active = $active;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateCreated(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date_created;
    }

    public function setDateCreated(\DateTimeInterface $date_created): self
    {
        $this->date_created = $date_created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Collection $roles
     */
    public function setRoles(Collection $roles): void
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getRoles(): Collection
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password): void
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }

    public function isVerified(): bool
    {
        return $this->isVerified;
    }

    public function setIsVerified(bool $isVerified): self
    {
        $this->isVerified = $isVerified;

        return $this;
    }

    public function addRole(Roles $role)
    {
        if ($this->roles->contains($role)) {
            return;
        }
        $this->roles->add($role);
    }

    public function removeRole(Roles $role)
    {
        if (!$this->roles->contains($role)) {
            return;
        }

        $this->roles->removeElement($role);
    }

}
```

Roles entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\RolesRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=RolesRepository::class)
 */
class Roles
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $system_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $name;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getSystemName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->system_name;
    }

    public function setSystemName(string $system_name): self
    {
        $this->system_name = $system_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Here is my LoginFormAuthenticator from Symfony documentantion:

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route') && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        // Check the user's password or other credentials and return true or false
        // If there are no credentials to check, you can just return true
        return true;
        throw new \Exception('TODO: check the credentials inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('index'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

I create one user manualy in database, make relations to roles table, and after  try to login with  this user it throw error like this

> Argument 3 passed to
> Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Token\PostAuthenticationGuardToken::__construct()
> must be of the type array, object given, called in
> /var/www/fitter/vendor/symfony/security-guard/AbstractGuardAuthenticator.php
> on line 35

In old way with roles like ["ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"] in User table app worked, but my goal is to use related roles.

I can't figure out how to pass correct type of roles to make login authenticator to work with this flow.

Comment: Abstract or not, your question is rather vague. You haven't actually presented a problem; what does _"I think I'm missing something in the whole concept."_ even refer to? Are you creating entities after creating tables (usually, one would do it the other way around)? What makes you think that your tables wouldn't be suitable? Which part of this system are you having troubles with?

Comment: I've edit the post, sorry about missing information.